# Should I build a table with jQuery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have some data in a database that will be displayed in a table based on certain filters(like a date interval). When making my Ajax calls, should I return the entire table printed in PHP and replace the content of the container with it or should I return a Json and build the table with jQuery? What is the best approach in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: checkout the datatable, jqgrid plugins.

Comment: usually tables have a lot of redundant markup so I would start to consider the payload difference between the methods

Comment: use jquery datatable plugins

Comment: if you want to load data fast I will suggest to do it on client side i.e. using JavaScript as bytes transferred will be less(minimal but if many ajax calls are there it does make a difference) and if that's not a concern then any would work perfectly fine